# Guitar choosing

Tags: acoustic-guitar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you identify a good acoustic guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/how-do-you-identify-a-good-guitar)
>   [How do I choose my first guitar for self-learning?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/979/how-do-i-choose-my-first-guitar-for-self-learning)

I want to study guitar playing but I'm total noob in this. So, how to choose guitar in shop which is tuned as well? Maybe you will advice me some brands which are tuned good by default?

Comment: I don't think you should focus on having your guitar tuned by default, since (1) you can do it yourself with a guitar tuner (they come cheap) (2) you'll eventually *have to* retune your guitar every once in a while.

Comment: So choosing Your first guitar is rather not about tunning. You find plenty of useful advice in this [question](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/how-do-you-identify-a-good-guitar) and also in this [question](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/979/how-do-i-choose-my-first-guitar-for-self-learning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid tuning is something which is done and maintained, for the most part, by the store. If you're asking about good beginner instruments, I'd recommend Yamaha as they have excellent quality-control (so you're unlikely to find a bad one) and are very competitively priced (so if you decide to not stick with it, you haven't wasted too much money).

Seeing as beginners often have difficulty determining good instruments from bad, I'd also recommend bringing a friend with you who already plays if possible.