# How should I choose a Ukulele?

Tags: instruments, ukulele

I am planning to buy a ukulele tomorrow, and I am a bit lost.  I did manage to figure out the differences between a Soprano Ukulele and a Concert Ukulele, so I have chosen an Concert Ukulele, which I assume fits my musical choices.

The problem is choosing a specific model, I've seen many brands available and I am currently considering the the [Aloha 30C Ukulele](http://www.dirkwitte.nl/nl/ukelele/28338-aloha-30c-ukelele-3700166317741.html) and the [Ibanez UKC 10](http://www.feedbackmusic.com/gitaar/ibanez-ukc-10-concert/100005502/FBR105960).

I am not sure which one I should pick, the reviews I've found from the Aloha are all in French, nothing interesting really.

How can I evaluate these ukeleles?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  If you check out the FAQ, you'll see that we don't answer questions related to shopping / brand choices.  If you can edit your question to pertain to performance practice, then I'm sure you'll get some great answers.

Comment: I think there's enough here that we don't have to close. Asking questions about _how to evaluate_ different models is fine, and that's mostly what this is about.

Comment: If you can try them in a shop, I think this would help you decide. I find that when I try instruments, I just 'know' when I find the one I like. It's unscientific, but if you love the feel of it then you might end up playing it more :)

Comment: @am75 Problem is, I cannot try the Ibanez :(

Comment: ok. At that price range, the wood will almost certainly be plywood, so it's probably down to construction quality, which is hard to judge like this. Based on familiarity and googlability I'd go for the Ibanez. (I've never heard of Aloha - possibly a European brand - whereas Ibanez are well known to make quality guitars, and that Ibanez model has 5 [positive] reviews on musiciansfriend.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the same considerations come in as for a guitar:

- [How do I choose my first guitar for self-learning?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/979/how-do-i-choose-my-first-guitar-for-self-learning)
- [How do you identify a good acoustic guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/how-do-you-identify-a-good-guitar)

Ukuleles are generally nylon strung, so you don't need to worry about truss rods. You might want to think about amplification, and electric-acoustic ukes are increasingly common.

The most important advice is equally true for all instruments: don't spend serious money on an instrument you haven't held in your own hands, and tried out.

What you're proposing to spend here is one step more expensive than the bottom-of-the-range ukuleles that seem to be everywhere. It might be worth spending €30 on a *really* cheap one, and learning the basics on it, so that you can visit a music shop and know what you're looking for when trying out more serious instruments.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Soprano is the most common size. It makes classical and traditional ukulele sound. The soprano is the lightest instrument. It is suitable for any level ukulele player, especially beginner ukulele player and those have smaller hands and fingers.

On the other side, the concert is bigger than the soprano. The concert is suitable for any level ukulele player but it may be comfortable for those who have larger hands and fingers.

https://ukulelesreview.com/best-ukulele-for-beginners/